# How to determine app is running in iphone or ipod programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

I want to check whether my application is running in iphone or ipod. How can I do this?

Comment: Actually there are better ways to do that. Try our sdk, it does a lot more than just tell you the device: www.AskingPoint.com

Answer (score 1):

use below code for finding current device

```
NSString *deviceStr = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
NSLog(@"device:%@",deviceStr);
```

if your device is iPod then it will return

```
iPod touch
```

if your device is iPhone

```
iPhone
```

if your device is iPad

```
iPad
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I found out answer for this

```
#define IS_IPHONE ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
#define IS_IPOD ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"])
```